# JanusGraph "NoHostAvailableException" in multi datacenter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, janusgraph

We are using JanusGraph 0.2.0 with Cassandra 3.11.1 and testing its support for geo diversity. Currently we have 2 Datacenters with 1 nodes in each and replication factor is 1 for both the datacenter.

`janusgraph-cassandra.properties`

```
storage.backend=cql
storage.cql.read-consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM
storage.cql.write-consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM
storage.cql.local-datacenter=dc2
storage.cql.only-use-local-consistency-for-system-operations=true
storage.cql.replication-strategy-options=dc1,1,dc2,1
storage.cql.replication-strategy-class = NetworkTopologyStrategy
```

When we have Cassandra running in both the nodes of datacenter, we are able to connect and create JanusGraph keyspace. However, when one datacenter goes down, and if we try to open a connection, we observe following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.249.55.111:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)))
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.reportNoMoreHosts(RequestHandler.java:211)
```

We have configured Local_Quorum, but still why is it using Quorum for establishing connection.

Update: nodetool status output

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
DN  10.249.55.108  283.54 KiB  256          100.0%            619242db-f0bd-4492-aeb6-2bb0ebfe4733  rack1
Datacenter: dc2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.249.55.111  294.75 KiB  256          100.0%            6ebe897e-94e3-44e5-99dc-055beb633e74  rack1
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of "nodetool status"

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, i have added nodetool status output.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a bug in the JanusGraph code. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/913) to track this. In the meantime, adding this line to your `janusgraph-cassandra.properties` is a workaround:

```
log.tx.key-consistent=true
```

Comment: Thanks Jason Plurad. Could you please explain us the significance of log.tx.key-consistent parameter.

Comment: This tells the graph that the transaction log is using a key consistent backend (such as Apache Cassandra or Apache HBase). As a result, it will pull in the configuration properties that are in the properties file when connecting to the transaction log table. Without that setting, it will use the default consistency level `QUORUM`.

Comment: Thanks Jason Plurad